# Is it possible to have a nested adjacent sibling selector with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove any `<div><br></div>` elements when they are in succession. Is it possible to do this purely with CSS? Open to other ideas as well as I am trying to avoid writing JavaScript.

```css
div br > div br {
  display: none;     //not working
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
<div><br></div>
<div>text</div>
<div><br></div> <!-- display none -->
<div><br></div> <!-- display none -->
<div>text</div>
<div><br></div> <!-- display none -->
<div><br></div> <!-- display none -->
<div><br></div> <!-- display none -->
<div>text</div>
```

Comment: the short answer is : No

Comment: Effectively you are after a parent selector as it is the parent `div` that contains a `br` you want to target. No such selector exists at this point. Javascript or jQuery is your only resort at this stage.

Comment: Why not remove all `<br>`s and rely on CSS to space out your real content?

Comment: You'd better fix the source of this ugly HTML. It does not work very good.

Comment: Here's a quick jQuery solution, should you go down that path: https://jsfiddle.net/8w1enc4q/ . It could probably be optimised.